# Session stops automatically

Tags: php

I have learned so much from stackoverflow. I have run into a problem that is strange, 
Here it goes.

I have coding that checks if a session has started and if not, I start the session. No problem there

Here is my code

```
If (session-id = "")
{Session_start();
/* setting session ids */
}
```

I have an include file that submits a form to the same script (script above)

But when returning to the page via post method, the session gets started again, as if the session stopped.

Edit

If (session_id == "")

The mistake there was a typo.

The problem I originally had was that upon first initialization, I had set session arrays

```
/* If statement */
$_Session['test'] = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
/* end of if statement */
```

When user submits data to the same script, the session array will be null, giving an error. The way I solved it was to put session_start on the top of the script and no longer on the if statement. That seemed to solve the problem, thanks for all your input.

Comment: well what is session-id  ?

Comment: That code doesn't look right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start the session at the top of every page, just to keep the session. That will not clear the running session, so you can just remove the condition for it to start.

Answer (score 4):

i think you want this

```
if(session_id() == '') {
     Session_start();
    /* setting session ids */
}
```

> [`session_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) returns the session id for the current session or the empty string ("") if there is no current session (no current session id exists).

---

also you  Call  `session_start()` more than one there is no problem in that since

> [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) - Start new or resume existing session

---

in the php version **`>=5.4.0`** you can also use [`session_status()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php) it

> [`session_status()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php) is used to return the current session status.

---

**Edited**

Well it seems that Starting session twice is problem in some case

I am quoting this comment of    [DaveRandom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/889949/daverandom)

> If The session is already started. You can't start it again. You can't resume something that isn't stopped. This will stop the message from appearing but I don't understand why you would want to call `session_start()` in the first place. Note also that `session_write_close()` doesn't destroy the local $_SESSION variable so make sure you don't try and write to it after you've closed the session.

so you can do this like

```
<?php

  var_dump(isset($_SESSION));
  session_start();
  var_dump(isset($_SESSION));
  session_write_close();
  var_dump(isset($_SESSION));
  session_start();
```

[codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ucQElu)

Comment: Via @Tuim on another answer: Calling `session_start()` more than once issues a notice. Per the manual: "As of PHP 4.3.3, calling session_start() after the session was previously started will result in an error of level E_NOTICE. Also, the second session start will simply be ignored."

Comment: @AgentConundrum well As of PHP 4.3.3, calling session_start() after the session was previously started will result in an error of level E_NOTICE. Also, the second session start will simply be ignored. its not problem in 5.3 or 5.4

Comment: I don't know about you, but I typically consider it a problem if my code is throwing E_NOTICEs.

Comment: What was wrong with the manual in this case? It clearly tells you that it'll throw a notice.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether `$_SESSION` is set.

```
isset($_SESSION) or session_start();
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/I3i9lv

Comment: You will get "Notice: A session had already been started" notices.